# Regex OR Alteration not working

Tags: c#, regex

I have below query and sample with or condion in betweeen two regex patterns

pattern : `\((?>\((?<c>)|[^()]+|\)(?<-c>))*(?(c)(?!))\)(?=[)[]GS)|(?=[^ ]*\$).*(?=[[]GS)`

Input : `$sense$[TM]  &  ( ( monitoring$  |  automat$  |  building$  |  facilit$ )[GS])  &   "9"[IC]`

Below desired output is achieved with first regex in pattern `\((?>\((?<c>)|[^()]+|\)(?<-c>))*(?(c)(?!))\)(?=[)[]GS)`

`(?=[^ ]*\$).*(?=[[]GS)` is required for another case

Desired output : `( ( monitoring$  |  automat$  |  building$  |  facilit$ )`

But if i use both patterns at once with "|" alteration it gives be below result

```
$sense$[TM]  &  ( ( monitoring$  |  automat$  |  building$  |  facilit$ )
```

Reason: second pattern after `|` is also executing.

Comment: What is `(?<-c>)`?

Comment: (?<-c>) is to get the content between ()[GS] ... to get track the end of the open bracket where it started. Basically for Or contion in the pattern both are executing even it got result from 1st condition

Comment: Do you have any doc about it? :)

Comment: [Balancing group construct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2)

Comment: Say more about this *another case*: *is required for **another case***. Please show something about it.